# How can I run XNA in VirtualBox on a Mac?

Tags: c#, xna, virtualbox

I know it's weird. XNA Version is 3.1 and VirtualBox version is 4.0.2.

Comment: Does the graphics driver within VirtualBox support DirectX? Remember, VirtualBox is not providing direct hardware access, so you'll likely be running a VirtualBox device driver for video, as opposed to the actual device driver for your card. VMware does the same thing. 

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-3-directx.html

You'll probably want to run through this to ensure that you have DirectX support within your virtual environment. I know this is for VirtualBox 3, but perhaps the process is similar.

Comment: If you are trying to run XNA on a VM because you have a different host Os and that is all, maybe check out MonoGame (a mono impl of XNA).

Comment: here is a way to run the xna 4.0 with the newest virtual box. it is parallels but it works with virtual box too!
http://leeyuentuen.byethost15.com/blog/?p=1393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the software [reference device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219625%28VS.85%29.aspx) that comes with [DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/directx). For me, that enabled running XNA related unit tests on a Hyper-V virtual machine. It should do the trick for any virtual environment since it implements a full DirectX device in software and does not rely on available hardware or virtualized drivers. It will not be blazingly fast but it should work.

Installing the core parts of the DirectX SDK is enough, no further installation or configuration is required.

(Almost forgot) In the code that sets up the device you must specify the device type to use:

```
var deviceType = (hardwareDevice ? DeviceType.Hardware : DeviceType.Reference);
var graphicsDevice = new GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter,
                                            deviceType,
                                            ...);
```

As a side note: in XNA 4.0, choosing reference or hardware device is moved to the `GraphicsAdapter` using the [UseReferenceDevice property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsadapter.usereferencedevice.aspx).

Comment: Looks helpful. I'll try this. Now, what if I want the compiled executable to be more compatible and include the same flexibility? Basically where it would be able to run on more machines without the Pixel Shader error messages coming up?

Comment: I ended up just installing Windows LOL since that is the best solution for me. But your solution is the closest.

Comment: Ah great, made me laugh :) glad to help though!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed it in VMware Fusion, which supports DirectX 9c. However, you may have to use the Reach game profile rather than the full HiDef one. This can be done easily in the game project properties window in Visual Studio.

I hope this helps, but as dotalchemy says, you will want to make sure support is there!

Answer (score 0):

Enable 3D Acceleration according to [DirectX in VirtualBox 3.0.0 - Pure joy is here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-3-directx.html) and the XNA project would run just fine.

Comment: I believe the OP already did this. Unfortunately, VirtualBox only has limited DirectX emulation, and it seems not to be enough to support the XNA Reach profile.